# What tools and techniques do I need to recreate this piece of furniture? (pic in description)

Tags: furniture, aluminum

[image: Blackhawk 47" chest from restorationhardware.com]

I don't plan on making a chest of drawers but am interested in the techniques involved so I could apply them to other furniture.

EDIT: close up picture
[image]

Comment: I think you need a [Robbie the Robot](http://www.uncleodiescollectibles.com/img_lib/Robby%20the%20Robot%2014%205-28-12.jpg).

Comment: It's probably just an aluminum skin over standard secondary-wood construction. If so, all you need is a way to cut and bend the aluminum pieces. Saw with metal-cutting blade would probably distort the metal less than tinsnips would. File and/or abrasives to de-burr (and probably slightly round over) the cut edges. A bending brake would help, but you can also just force the metal around a suitable form (possibly the wooden frame itself) -- I've seen that done with brass, though scoring the bend first helps. Whatever nails you consider adequately decorative to hold the aluminum in place.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that those are thin pieces of tin nailed to a wooden cabinet with brass tacks. I think it is quite cool actually, sort of steampunk.

To do it large scale you would be best served with a sheet metal shear (think of a heavy duty paper shear), a pinch roller (adjustable twin steel rollers mounted vertically which you spin with a handle whilst passing sheet metal between, to set a curved bend), and maybe a sheet metal "brake" (a sheet metal bender for straight bends as opposed to curves). Also various metal working tools: vise grips, awl, tin snips (straight, right-hand, left-hand), various files, ball-pene hammers, small anvil, etc.

You can buy some ["DIY" sheet metal work contraptions](http://www.harborfreight.com/garage-shop/metal-shaping-equipment/30-inch-shear-press-brake-and-slip-roll-5907.html) that combine a roller, shear, and brake for fairly cheap. Check on e-bay.

Comment: Screwed, not tacked; and the metal can't be *too* thin as the edges in the close ups do not appear to be razor sharp. Perhaps 12 to 14 gauge.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger, my answer was posted prior to OP edit with close-up pic. I could not see the screw heads in the original pic. Looking carefully, I think the edges may actually be rolled over/folded to prevent sharp edges.